# Unable to profile simple C++ program in Instruments: "failed to execute loader thread"

Tags: xcode, macos, apple-m1, instruments, xcode-instruments

I made a new command-line tool C++ project in Xcode, with the following `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
}
```

When I try to profile it in Instruments with any template, I get the following error before my program even starts:

```
Failed to execute loader thread for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTInstrumentsFoundation.framework/Resources/liboainject.dylib in target; target process <pid> likely exited
```

I get the same error when I try running Instruments with `xctrace`.

How do I get Instruments to properly load my programs?

Setup:

- Xcode version: 13.4.1 (13F100)
- Hardware: 2020 M1 MacBook Air

Comment: Can you get Instruments to profile a new Mac App project instead of a command-line tool project? The error message indicates the program finishes before Instruments can start profiling. All your program does is prints "Hello, world" and exits. You may need a longer running program for Instruments to work.

Comment: @SwiftDevJournal that actually seems to be the problem, I didn't think that having a program too fast for the profiler was possible... 

Thanks!